# Currency Formatting: Remove insignificant Zeros

Tags: c#, formatter

I am displaying a currency value of up to 5 decimal places with `{0:C5}` but when there are insignificant zeros, they should not get shown.

With a simple decimal I simply use `{0:0.#####}` but I need this with Currency Formatters as it's a multi-language system.

Edit: Forgot to mention I am using composite formatting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This setup almost seems like a design flaw.  Depends a lot on the use-case, but often you'll have a fixed number of digits because of alignment or the typical way a monetary value is represented.  For instance, something costing 4 dollars and 30 cents in USD would come off as odd displayed as $4.3

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using composite formatting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A bus fare costing 4 dollars and 30 cents in HKD is perfectly normal to be displayed as $4.3 in Hong Kong, where $4.30 is also as common in price labels in goods. The cent is no longer used in daily life but remains for accounting purposes. Therefore OP's question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use `IFormatProvider` and `ICustomFormatter`

```
public class NumberFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        //TODO: Get your own NumberFormatInfo from CurrentCulture instead of this.
        private static readonly NumberFormatInfo NumberFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").NumberFormat;

        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            if (formatType != typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Format");
            }

            return this;
        }

        public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            var supportedTypes = new Type[] { typeof(decimal), typeof(double), typeof(int), typeof(float) };

            if (!supportedTypes.Contains(arg.GetType()))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (format.ToUpper() != "C")
            {
                return null;
            }

            var result = arg.ToString();

            var isFraction = result.IndexOf(".", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0;
            if (isFraction)
            {

                result = RemoveTrailingZero(result);
                var numberOfDigits = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(".", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1).Length;

                if (numberOfDigits < 5)
                {
                    NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits = numberOfDigits;
                    NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = numberOfDigits;
                }
                else
                {
                    NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 5;
                    NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 5;
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToDecimal(result).ToString("C", NumberFormatInfo);
        }

        private string RemoveTrailingZero(string number)
        {
            var lastIndexOfZero = number.LastIndexOf("0", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (lastIndexOfZero == number.Length - 1)
            {
                number = number.Remove(lastIndexOfZero);
                return RemoveTrailingZero(number);
            }
            else
            {
                return number;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the usage and output

```
        var numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
        var amount = 10000.1230M;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(numberFormatter, "Amount is {0:C}", amount));
        amount = 10000.12305M;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(numberFormatter, "Amount is {0:C}", amount));
        amount = 10000.00M;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(numberFormatter, "Amount is {0:C}", amount));
        amount = 10000.1010M;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(numberFormatter, "Amount is {0:C}", amount));

Amount is $10,000.123
Amount is $10,000.12305
Amount is $10,000
Amount is $10,000.101
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrive amount of significant digits from decimal value and then generate currency format with number you get

```
private string GenerateCurrencyFormatFor(decimal value)
{
    const decimal NORMALIZE_COEFFICENT = 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m;
    const int MAX_DIGITS = 5;

    decimal normalizeValue = value/ NORMALIZE_COEFFICENT;

    var decimalBits = decimal.GetBits(normalizeValue);
    var decimalScaleInfo = decimalBits[3];

    var scaleInfoBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimalScaleInfo);
    var significantDigitsCount = (int)scaleInfoBytes[2];

    var actualDigitsCount = Math.Min(significantDigitsCount, MAX_DIGITS);

    return $"C{actualDigitsCount}";
}
```

Of course you can "refactor" that function even in one liner, but I want it so to show the idea.

Then use it

```
var value = 123.4500m;  
var currencyFormat = GenerateCurrencyFormatFor(value);
var printValue = value.ToString(currencyFormat);
// will print £123.45 

var value = 123.1234567m; // will print £123,12346
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.TrimEnd(new Char[] { '0' } )` after your normal formatting to get rid of leading zeros.

```
var number = (0.476434323).ToString("C5").TrimEnd(new Char[] { '0' } );
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using composite formatting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still this should work as it's been tested in a previous project of mine ;)

Comment: btw you can use just `new[] { '0' }` for brevity

Comment: As @PaddySe commented in another answer, "This won't work because some currencies have their currency symbol after the amount (e.g. "200,50 kr" for SEK)."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put currency symbol explicitly? e.g.:

```
String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0}{1:0.#####}", cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, 1.00005M))
```

Also see [How to Remove the Trailing Zeros of Precision From a C# Decimal](http://blog.zerosharp.com/how-to-remove-the-trailing-zeros-of-precision-from-a-c-number-decimal/)

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using composite formatting https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com: Can you share a bigger piece of code how you're formatting the string?

Comment: This won't work because some currencies have their currency symbol *after* the amount (e.g. "200,50 kr" for SEK).